# TextArea joins as one string to PHP how can I set the other strings in new line with help of delimiter

Tags: php, html

I've tried searching all over google and tried a similar problem and answers yet I still didn't get my problem done.

So basically, I'm making an HTML to write user input in a textbox which is the user would input:

```
Dog,
cat,
coronavirus,
Fever,
Cough,
```

Then into my PHP code, I capture it with:

```
$input = $_GET['contents'];
```

So I tried this one which I saw from googling and it doesn't have an explanation but logically its about array:

```
$input= explode(array(",", ""), $input)[0];
```

It works but the problem is that it only shows the first output which is:

```
Dog 
Dog 
Dog 
Dog 
Dog
```

But when I tried to remove the delimiter code, it shows one string only:

```
Dog,cat,coronavirus,Fever,Cough,
```

I thought about it something related to array but I'm not sure, is there any way to display all of them per line and with the help with delimiter?

UPDATE:
So I tried doing `print_r($secs);` and it shows like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Dog [1] => cat ) 
Array ( [0] => )
```

My accomplishment is to read all of the arrays one by one in another line instead of joining it as one strings. Sorry for bad english and im trying my best to explain.

Comment: Get rid of the `[0]`

Comment: Textarea is already a single string. Can you please edit the question and explain what you're trying to accomplish (rather than how you want to do it)?

Comment: I already tried that and It didn't work. I tried echoing $input and somehow it shows the word "Array" while having the [0] in it shows the first line the user inputted in the textbox which is quite confusing. I assume this is related to array's, Any ideas?

Comment: use `print_r()` not `echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need the `array()` line.

Instead

```
if(strpos($_GET['contents'],',') !== false) { //check for commas first
    $input = explode(',' , $_GET['contents']);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($input); //gives you the array
    echo '</pre>';   
}
```

to access each string individually, call the offset. For example, `print_r($input[0]);`

Also a friendly piece of advice. You seem like a beginner. You do not have to execute multiple commands in one line. Write your code step by step.

Comment: I'm a beginner actually and I want to learn some PHP. And this actually worked for me. Thank you sir.